# Using gdaldem to match cumulative count colouring of QGIS?

Tags: raster, gdal, color, gdaldem

I am trying to colour a single band grey raster (NDVI) using gdal to match the same colouring when I bring the raster into QGIS and colour it with a cumulative count cut (2%/98%). When I use the code:

```
  gdaldem color-relief raster_ndvi.tif colour_percent2test.txt -alpha  raster_ndvi_colour.tif
```

with my colour textfile:

```
98%  26   153  71      
74%  161  209  106    
50%  255  255  197   
26%  254  177  101      
2%   255   0    0 
nv   0     0    0    0
```

I get a similar raster as the QGIS version, but I don't see as much red

This is the QGIS output:

[image: QGIS output]

And this is what I get from the gdal code:

[image: Gdal output]

I have also tried using a colour textfile:

```
100% 26   153  71
98%  26   153  71      
74%  161  209  106    
50%  255  255  197   
26%  254  177  101      
2%   255   0    0 
0%   255   0    0 
nv   0     0    0    0
```

and it ends up looking the exact same as the other attempt.

Any suggestions on how I can get my colouring to match QGIS without typing in the actual raster values in the colour ramp?

I want to be able to colour multiple rasters this way without needing to know the raster values to type them into the textfile each time (so 0.37 =  red, 0.504 = orange, etc.) as this would take more time and I may as well just use QGIS instead.

Answer (score 2):

The cumulative count cuts are the 2nd and 98th percentiles of the raster band values. You can achieve this styling with gdal and numpy the following way.

```
import gdal
import numpy as np

src_ds = gdal.Open(single_band_raster)
src_band = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

array = src_band.ReadAsArray()
p2 = np.percentile(array, 2)
p98 = np.percentile(array, 98)
```

Then your color file should look like

```
p2 first_color some_opacity
....
some_intermediate_value some_intermediate_color some_opacity
...
p98 last_color some_opacity
```

for example

```
p2 = 30
p98 = 75

30 26 153 71
45 255 255 97
75 255 0 0
```

And you might want to exclude the

```
nv 0 0 0 0
```

line because, it will color values < p2 and > p98 transparent or whatever color you define. It you omit the line, values < p2 will get the first color and values > p98 will get the last color. I believe this is what happens in QGIS.

Also, your p2 and p98 values might be a little different than in QGIS because there 2 ways to calculate them in QGIS: Estimate (faster), Actual (slower). Estimate is the default.